# working with ajax, mysql and php

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I have to transfer data from one div to another, I am using AJAX to do this.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#aq").click(function(){
var name1 = $("#n1").val();

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",  
  url: "risultato.php"     
  data: "name1=" + name1 ,
  dataType: "html",      
  success: function(msg)
  {
    $("#risultato1").html(msg);          
  },
  error: function()
  {
    alert("Chiamata fallita, si prega di riprovare..."); 
  }
});
});
});
</script>';



<form name="modulo1'.$dationennx['id'].'">  

<input type="hidden" name="name1" value="'.$dati['id'].'" 
id="n1'.$dationennx['id'].'">
<a href="javascript:rispondithread(\'homeq\');"  
id="aq">'.stripslashes($dationennx['oggetto']).'</a><br>
</form>


<script>
    function rispondithread(h) {        
     $("#rispondithreadforum").attr("style", "display:block;");         
}   
</script>`
```

I am fetching the data from my table from the 'risultato.php' page, which i want to use to show a textarea on my main page with the fetched data.

```
 <?php


$nome = $_POST['name1'];


    $query = "SELECT * FROM login2.podcast 
    WHERE login2.podcast.id = '$nome'
    ORDER BY login2.podcast.data DESC";
    $dati = mysql_query($query);     



while($ris = mysql_fetch_array($dati) ){

echo'   
<textarea class="form-control textareaabc" readonly tabindex="8">'.stripslashes($ris['testo']).'</textarea>';   


}

 ?>
```

It doesn't work if i try to fetch the data using mysql_query, but it does when i try echoing the post data in the page.

```
$nome = $_POST['name1'];    
echo $nome
```

This writes the '$nome' variable in my main page.

```
$nome = $_POST['name1'];   
echo'<input type="text" value="'.$nome.'" name="nome">';
```

i don't understand this. why it doesn't work? what's wrong?

Comment: myslq? what is that? If it says a question with same title already exists, try to read the Q. If it doesn't solve your problem, be more specific on title.

Comment: why are you still using the deprecated `mysql_` library? It was discontinued many years ago due to security issues, and removed entirely in PHP7. No new code should be written using that library. Switch to `mysqli_` or `PDO` a.s.a.p, and start using parameterised queries - right now your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks and potentially other threats from using a dead library.

Comment: Make use of object notation when passing data and ensure that the data is reaching the PHP script.

Comment: "it doesn't work with the query mysql". Well then...have you checked what the final query string looks like? Have you run that query in Workbench or PHPMyAdmin? Does it return any results? Are there any rows in you DB which actually match it? If you tell us what the value of $nome1 is that you're using, and a sample of your database, we can tell you if the query is right or not.

Answer (score 0):

**It is highly likely that there is no data for the '$nome' variable in your table**
Make sure that you are actually receiving data from the database, does it print out the textarea?
 If not, you do not have any id in your podcast table table matching the '$nome' variable.

**Testing your code**


Try checking if you actually get anything back when you print something out in that page, could you possibly be pointing to the wrong page?

**other**

Overall, i would recommend using PDO or atleast mysqli, MySQL is no longer supported since PHP 7 and deprecated since PHP 5. 
See: [PHP.net documentation about mysql extension](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php)

Comment: "It is highly likely that there is no data for the '$nome' variable in your table". No, this directly contradicts the clear statement in the question: "`$nome = $_POST['name1'];    
echo $nome`
This writes the '$nome' variable in my main page". Read more carefully. The problem is the query, which the answer from the OP has now verified.

Comment: ADyson the table could currently not have the value of the '$nome' variable, i didn't say anything about the variable itself not being set.

Answer (score 0):

sorry, i forget to include the connection to the database into the file risultato.php :P

thanks to everybody